# Using different servers for front-end and back-end?

Tags: sql-server, database-recommendation

I recently noticed that the load time of my website has slowed significantly.  I'm not a developer, but my programmer mentioned this is due to the large amount of data that is being searched through when a user comes to the homepage (due to recording tracking information).

Would using separate servers for the front-end code and the back-end database help resolve this problem?  Any recommendations I can talk to my developer about would be helpful.

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your server config it might.  It is usually recommended that you don't have anything else running on the SQL Server other than SQL Server so that you can dedicate all the memory to the SQL Server instance.  You may also need to do some index tuning to help solve the performance problem.